# String formatting prob for making database value inside a file

Tags: java, regex, string, formatting, string-formatting

I have a bean class which does maintain user data:

soppose I have created a postgresql DB table like this:

```
StringBuffer sqlStr = new StringBuffer();
sqlStr.append("CREATE TABLE Users ("
        user_id         bigint,
        username        character varying NOT NULL,
        biography       character varying NOT NULL
);
```

& I want to make a query command and inject my String data inside it:

```
    sqlStr.append("INSERT INTO users(" +
            "user_id, username, biography)" +
            "\n\tVALUES (" + user.getID()+ "," + user.getUsername() + "," + user.getBiography()+");";
```

my problem is for example if the data coming from my method has quote or double quote or "," my command will become wrong suppose that the user biography is something like this :

> hello, I'm Mr X an "IT Pro" ...

If I run my application and save the output inside a file called query.sql I can't use it because my query command is wrong because of quote & double quote, something like this:

```
INSERT INTO users(userid, username, biography)
     VALUES(2, 'Mehdi', 'hello, I'm Mr X an "IT Pro" ..');
```

how Can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **never ever** use the above method for constructing SQL queries.

"Why not?" you ask, well; where to start. The classic example is [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/), the more general problem is [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). This leaves your program open to attack but also to random failure - like the situation you describe.

Now, the solution. Always use `PreparedStatement` to construct your query. In your example

```
final String query = "INSERT INTO users(user_id, username, biography) VALUES (?,?,?)";
final PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setInt(1, user.getID());
ps.setString(2, user.getUsername());
ps.setString(3, user.getBiography());
ps.executeUpdate();
```

A much nicer syntax to use with is the the `SET` syntax rather than the traditional `VALUES` syntax. The query would then look like

```
final String query = "INSERT INTO users SET user_id = ?, username = ?, biography = ?";
```

**EDIT**

The OP is building a query for a script file, not executing a query in the code.

There is a utility class in Apache Commons Lang, [`StringEscapeUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html). This has an `escapeSql` method. Looking at the source code, all this does is escape single quotes with another single quote.

This works if you build your queries with single quotes:

```
VALUES (" + user.getID()+ ",'" + user.getUsername() + "'...
```

So the query, once the example value is inserted will go from:

```
VALUES (10 ,'hello, I'm Mr X an "IT Pro"'...
```

Will become

```
VALUES (10 ,'hello, I''m Mr X an "IT Pro"'...
```

The apostrophe in "I'm" is now escaped and harmless.

Note that you obviously need to escape the values and not the query, so (assuming you have a `static` import for the class)

```
VALUES (" + user.getID()+ ",'" + escapeSql(user.getUsername()) + "'...
```

But does not escape other sql characters, percent signs for example.

This is really a stop-gap measure to make the code work while you come up with a more robust solution. And you should come up with a more robust solution.

Comment: dude this case is somehow different. we want to make this file & give to some of our client & then they can use the downloaded file to load the tables & info inside their own prepaired databse. did you get me?

Comment: Well then you should build the database using the approach I suggest and use the [pg_dump](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pg_dump) command. If you insist on hacking something together then [this](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#line.692) should at least help a little.

Comment: ok I'll explain again ! our program have nothing to do with any database. we have some data which are so important & also we have some pro users. our pro users have a program which works with their database. we have to feed them with our data & then they have to import data using pgadmin or postgres query to their own databases so our job is just to provide them the query commands & data so that they can copy paste & update their databases. in this scenario we don't have any database around ourselves we just want to give query command file to our pro users, get it ?

Comment: in fact we have a web site which will let user download this file & after the pro user download the file he/she can copy paste the query commands & update his/her database & let their app work with that database!

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment, you can use [StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeSql(java.lang.String)) but this will only get you so far, that will solve your immediate problem. But you should really be exchanging database data using `pg_dump` - it is not a big task to use a temporary database to build your data and then dump it and that will save you _immense_ headaches in the long run.

Comment: StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql is what I'm looking for !

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use **PreparedStatement**? That will also give you better performance as the SQL will be pre-compiled on DB side.

Or

You can escape the quotes using 
String.replaceAll http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: the problem is that we don't actually want to query database ourselvs, we want to make a file which do have all info inside it, then the user download the file & can input tables & info inside his/her own database, get it ?

Comment: NP...You can still use pstmt.setString(1, user.getID());.That's recommended approach.

Comment: hey man we DON'T WANT TO USE statement & sql connection methods !